# UIPickerview in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

How to place UIPickerView programmatically in a subView with out using Interface Builder?

Comment: you won't get an answer to 'plz send me teh codez'.  You must show what you've tried, what you've found, what does/doesn't work and you'll get help with a solution.  Google (or even search within SO) is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

Hey! U can make UIPickerView programmatically....

In- viewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,320, 500)];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [pickerView setDelegate:self];
        [pickerView release];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return ; //give components here
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return ;   //give rows here
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {   return ;  // give titles }

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    //Do the step here
}
```

And in your viewController.h class never forgot to do this

`@interface viewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate>`

Hope this may help u.....for more help follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465371/uipickerview-without-ib) ..

Comment: I have 5 main views.I have to place this UIPicker in subView(name as myView) and pickerView displays "1 - 30" values. Can u send me, how can i do this?

Comment: awesome! @user553215 show respect with voting up for that nice answer ;)