# how to add picker view programmiticaly for list of image names

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone development.In my application i want to add image picker for list of image names.here i added picker view and i dont no how to add list of image names programmiticaly in iphone with out using IB.

can any one plz give me code for displaying image names programmiticaly  in pickerview.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: check the documentation first

Comment: What do you have so far?  Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user549767 the answer of dks1725 is correct way to give images to your pickerview.....but in order to add pickerView programatically follow the below link....

[UIPickerview in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559867/uipickerview-in-iphone/4560120#4560120)

Answer (score 1):

in viewDidLoad method make an array of your image names like below

-(void)viewDidLoad

{
    arr=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image_name1",@"image_name2",@"image_name3",nil];

}

Now in picker view's delegate method write below code

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{

```
return 1;
```

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

```
return [arr count];
```

}

-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

return [arr objectAtIndex:row];

}